# Writing and Reading Objects over Java NIO non blocking SocketChannels

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, nio, nonblocking

I am new to Socket programming, and I am trying to write a simple chat application.My server utilizes a HashSet of Strings to store user name information and I want to pass the `HashSet` from the server to the client. I was able to do this before with `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` over regular Sockets. However, now I am using `SocketChannel` and it does not allow this I get the following exception:

```
java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException
```

So i searched the web on how to do this and everyone says something different, and most go way over my head. Is there a simple way to do this without completely overriding the `writeObject` and `readObject` methods myself?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: it's possible: it's also too hard. Stick to blocking mode.

Comment: @EJP Lol thanks, I need to do this in non-blocking as part of my Network Programming class.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you either don't use non-blocking mode or don't use serialization.

If you must, you need to serialize to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, get the length, send the length, send the bytes, receive the length, keep reading, accumulating data until you have the correct length of data, put it into a `ByteArrayInputStream`, and deserialize from that. Not easy, especially the hand-waving around 'keep reading'. And it wastes both time and space.

Comment: Thank you, Does nobody have a generic template of this written somewhere? you would think this is a common issue.

Comment: The question has been asked here before.

Comment: i mean some sort of class or method that employs Java generics to handle this.

Comment: The question has been asked *and answered* here before. It's a bit difficult to express as a single class or method, as it's inextricably bound up with your `select()` loop. I don't know what Generics has to do with it.